# why I can't use variables in razor conditional statements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is the .cshtml code:

```
@switch (ViewBag.StockLevel)
{
    case 0:
    @:Out of Stock
       break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
       <b>Low Stock (@ViewBag.StockLevel)</b>
       break;
    default:
       @:@ViewBag.StockLevel
       break;
}
```

I don't understand why I can't modify the default as:

```
default:
   ViewBag.StockLevel
```

I mean after the default keyword, it is C# statement, isn't that plain `ViewBag.StockLevel` is what we need?

Comment: ViewBag.StockLevel is not c# statement...

Comment: Whatever is inside the case/default blocks isn't a C# statement, it's a Razor expression that the engine is going to (conditionally) render - so if you change it to ViewBag.StockLevel, you'll get "ViewBag.StockLevel" as displayed text.

Comment: @DarthVeyda  no I don't get "ViewBag.StockLevel" as displayed text. it is a compilation error in VS

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov   how come ViewBag.StockLevel is not c# statement?

Comment: @slowjams My bad - it's @: ViewBag.StockLevel that will display as text, but the point about Razor engine expecting a Razor expression still stands. Also you don't need @: for a Razor expression - it's redundant. Also-2: is it absolutely necessary to do this in the view? This is exactly the thing that you want to have as a model field and set it up in the controller - are there any reasons you cannot do that?

Comment: @DarthVeyda  I just don't understand why `default:
   ViewBag.StockLevel` produces error?